# how to get folder name that ends with a number in python

Tags: python, module, operating-system, shutil

I have a folder that is structured like this

```
post
-----1
------10am
-----------images
-----2
-------10am
-----------images
-----3
------10am
-----------images
```

this folder is up to 31 with the same subfolder '10am' and inside that is another folder 'images'

in another folder, I have all the image and .txt files that that I need to copy based on folder name in python
[image: files inside another folder]

So what I need to do now is copy
'2.jpg' inside 'post\2\10am\images' and
'2.txt' inside ''post\2\10am' and so on

here is my code so far:

```
import os,shutil

sampleFiles = r"\practice image and text"
destination = r"\posts"
time = '10am'

sample = os.listdir(sampleFiles)
#  sample = ['10.jpg', '10.txt', '11.jpg', '11.txt', '13.png', '13.txt', '16.jpg', '16.txt', '17.jpg', '17.txt', '18.jpg', '18.txt', '2.jpg', '2.txt', '20.jpg', '20.txt', '23.jpg', '23.txt', '24.jpg', '24.txt', '25.jpg', '25.txt', '27.jpg', '27.txt', '3.jpg', '3.txt','4.jpg', '4.txt', '5.jpg', '5.txt', '6.jpg', '6.txt', '9.jpg', '9.txt']


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(destination):
  for folderName in dirs:
  #get root + foldername
  rootWithFolder = os.path.join(root, folderName)

  #get path to date
  pathToDate = rootWithFolder.endswith(int(folderName)) # how to get the number?

  # get path to image folders
  if rootWithFolder.endswith('images'):
     pathToImage = rootWithFolder

  #copy .jpg files to pathToImage
  shutil.copy(sampleFiles + '\\' + str(pathToDate) + '.jpg'   , pathToImage) #not the most elegant way

  #copy .txt files to pathToDate
  shutil.copy(sampleFiles + '\\' + str(pathToDate) + '.txt'   , pathToDate + '\\' + 'time') #not the most elegant way
```

in my code, I am stuck on how to get `pathToDate` so I can just copy it based on the name of the folder,

I tried using `def` like this:

```
def allfiles(list):
 for i in range(len(list)):
  return list[i] # returns only the first value of the list
  # print(list[i]) #but this one returns all the value of the list

 allfiles(sample)
```

but it only returns 1 instance of the list.

My question is, how can I get the folder that is named as a `number` and ignore the `strings` like `10am folder` and `images folder`

or is there a better way to do this? Thank you

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear? Why does  pathToDate = rootWithFolder.endswith(int(folderName)) not work?

Comment: it works, but it has an error at the end, you see, `folderName` returns:  `1
10
11
12
13
14
...
...
10am
images
10am
images` 

it works on the numbers like 1, 10 , 11. But when it hits '10am', it gives an error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10am'` How can I only get the folder with names of number like 1, 10, 11 and so on but not '10am' and 'images'

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled: [`str.endswith`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=endswith#str.endswith) actually requires a `str` as argument and returns `bool`. So I don't quite understand what you are trying to do here: `rootWithFolder.endswith(int(folderName))` ? (1) You give it an `int`. (2) Do you really want `True`/`False` as part of a path name (could well be)?

Comment: What I am trying to do is get the folder name which is `1` `2` `3` `4` and so on and so forth. I used `int` because I think that I can get the value so I can match it with `2.jpg` `3.jpg` `4.jpg` and so on...  After matching it and returning true, I can use it to copy the image to `/posts/2/10am/images` `/posts/3/10am/images` and so on... Whereas the Folder name `2` , `3`   will have  `/posts/2/10am/images/2.jpg` `/posts/3/10am/images/3.jpg`. The `int` is something I saw searching this site and I am still finding others ways other than `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a suggestion if you're still looking for a solution... I'd go the other way round:

```
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import copy

sample_folder = Path("practice image and text")
dest_folder = Path("posts")

for file in sample_folder.glob("*.*"):
    number, suffix = file.name.split(".")
    if suffix == "txt":
        copy(file, dest_folder / number / "10am")
    else:
        copy(file, dest_folder / number / "10am" / "images")
```